# How to add slowness and blindness when you hit something?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I am trying to make a Dead by daylight map in Minecraft. When a player hits something they should get **slowness** and **blindness** for 5 seconds, but I don't know the commands necessary to do this.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "hit something"? As in, collide with a block or punch something?

Comment: like hit with a weapon.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code builder command [image: Example] it might take a little time to duplicating this for every item and weapon you need.